# How does Stress work for characters with multiple Affiliation dice?

Tags: stress, marvel-heroic-roleplaying

Some characters in MHR can have various levels of Affiliation. For example, Thanos has the following Affiliations: *Solo 3d10, Buddy d6, Team 2d8*.

Now let's suppose Thanos is in a conflict with some PCs by himself (Solo Affiliation), and they manage to remove two of his Affiliation dice.

Skreet then arrives, and they act with their Buddy Affiliation. What happens?

A - Thanos uses his Buddy d6 Affiliation, it is not affected by the Stress taken while in Solo.

B - All of Thanos Affiliations have lost 2 dice. Thanos cannot act as Buddy anymore.

C - All of Thanos Affiliations have lost 2 dice. Thanos is Stressed Out if he acts as Buddy.

D - His Affiliations cannot be reduced to less than his maximum Affiliation at that time. If he loses one die, his Affiliations become *Solo 2d10, Buddy d6, Team 2d8*. If he loses one additional die, they become *Solo d10, Buddy d6, Team d8*. If he loses one more die, he is Stressed Out.

Solution D seems the most reasonable one, but I have no idea if this is how the rules are actually working.

**Do the rules mention what happens when this kind of characters lose Affiliation dice?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Large-Scale Threat rules (OM115) and the rules for Affiliation (OM62), the answer is **A**. He would roll his single d6 Buddy affiliation with no other penalty. This is intentional, as it allows for imposing threats to not be one-shotted.

However, once the heroes have gotten Thanos down to a single Solo die -- and good on them for doing so -- he's still better off acting Solo or gathering an army (to use his 2d8 Team) than trying to act in concert with Skreet as his Buddy. At the very least, he should consider fleeing the scene, keeping himself Solo. (If you have 2d12 in the Doom Pool at this time, you might consider expending them to make this happen.)

Your answer "D" suggests that even though he's using his Buddy affiliation, he would lose dice from Solo regardless. That isn't the case.

Comment: What about his Team Affiliation? After losing two dice of Solo Affiliation, does he still have Team 2d8?

Comment: He does; I've made the entry clearer on that point. Of course, to use Team, he'd have to do something in-game to gather a horde of people to help him -- I'm reminded of the Chitauri army in the Avengers movie.

Answer (score 0):

*Fair warning*: In the areas where the rules aren't 100% comprehensive such as this, I try to adjust my interpretations to maximize the aspects of the game that my groups prefer. That is, we try to make it as logical and as simple as possible, but in a pinch we'll sacrifice logic for simplicity and ease/speed of game play.

For LST's, we clearly don't want them to be especially easier or harder to take down simply because of how they're affiliated. It should impact their effectiveness, (i.e. their dice pools) but it shouldn't be shifting their stress tracks around. So your options B and C are right out. We don't want silly cases where Thanos buddies up with a Skreet and that causes him to faint dead away, or he gets punched out by Howard the Duck because he was in Buddy affiliation and a d8 stressed him out. For this reason, I always use the largest Affiliation dice pool as the "stress" track. For most LSTs, this is the Solo Affiliation.

When an LST is creating dice pools, I use whichever Affiliation the LST is in. So if Thanos is in Buddy affiliation, his Affiliation die is a d6, but he's still taking stress against the 3d10 (from his Solo Affiliation). This can present situations where the LST is down to one die of stress, but because they're in a Team affiliation they're getting multiple (typically smaller) dice. Unlike your D case, we don't degrade other affiliations that may have more dice than the LST has left in their Solo affiliation. That's a little counterintuitive, since we're used to the LST getting weaker as we hammer on them, and in this case we're not reducing the Affiliation die in use, so we don't get that advantage. However, in most cases this makes some sense narratively, because the Team or Buddy dice represent the LST using other characters to manage the situation, so the effect of their own degraded status is minimized. Plus it's a little piece of paperwork that we don't have to track that doesn't usually have a major impact anyway.

Lastly, in a sense we treat the multiple Affiliation dice as individual stress tracks. That is, I can physically stress out one of his dice, emotionally stress out a second, complicate out a third, and so on until I take him down. Different types of stress or complications that don't exceed the die size can stick just like they would on a normal character. So Thanos can have a d8 of physical stress, a d6 of mental stress, a d8 of emotional stress, and a d10 Enraged complication all sitting on him for attackers to pick and choose from when opposing him. But if that complication gets pushed to a d12 or higher, it takes out one of his 3d10 Solo affiliation dice dropping him to 2d10, and the Complication goes with it.

**TL;DR**

We use A, but we count all damage against the highest affiliation, regardless of which affiliation they are in and using for their rolls. Each die can be stressed or complicated out by any type of damage that exceeds it. The LST doesn't go down until each of those dice are stressed or complicated out. And we don't discount the other Affiliations. Even when he's down to 1d10 in Solo, in Team he still gets to use 2d8.

Answer (score -3):

To stress him out, You need to deal d12 stress, three times.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  To make this a good answer, you should probably explain a little more about why, so that people might understand why this answer is correct. As it stands, people are unlikely to upvote it and the question asker is unlikely to use your answer, since there's no way they'd understand it.

Comment: Welcome to the site. There are a couple of problems with your answer. The first one is that is hard to understand from your answer how does it answer the question that have been asked. A sentence or two connecting between your answer and the question will do the trick. In addition, it will be far more helpful if you will quote the source that gives this information. It is not enough to answer a question, you also have to prove your answer for it to stand a test. When you will do those 2 things it will be a much better answer and you will feel it also.